# Inserting array in mongodb in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

i have two variable `name` and `place`

```
var name = 'ram';
var place = ['agra','delhi'];
```

my Schema is like

```
var Person= new Schema({
    about :
               {
                    name: {type : String},
                    place: {type : String}
               }
            ,     
});
```

I used query

```
    var person = new Person({
                      about : 
                            {
                              name : name,
                              place : place
                            }
                    });
   person.save(function(){});
```

but the problem is that `place` store as a `string` in database

```
name : 'ram',
place : 'agra,delhi'
```

,so when i applying a query for searching `place='agra'` ,it gives `null` output.

But when i search `place='agra,delhi'` it produces result.

I want that this `place` store as array in database like

```
name : 'ram',
place : ['agra','delhi']
```

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your schema to store places as array

```
var Person= new Schema({
    about : [
               {
                    name: {type : String},
                    places: [{type : String}]
               }
            ],     
});
```

Comment: can u please suggest me a query fror searching place='delhi'.

Comment: it'll be `db.col.find({'about.place' : 'delhi'})`, read the mongo db and mongoose documentations

Comment: thnx..and sorry ,i was using wrong database...so it was null everytimes